# Aggregation of conditional probabilities

Tags: probability, bayesian

Let's say that I have a population that I can split into two subgroups, containing $60 \% $ and $40 \% $ of the population respectively.

And I know the probability of some event in each of the two groups:

$P_1(A|B) = p_1$

$P_2(A|B) = p_2$

I want to calculate the probability of the event in the entire population. Can we simply assume that it will be:

$P(A|B) = 0.6p_1 + 0.4p_2$

Comment: One thing that might help is the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have probability of $A$ given $B$ and being member of a subpopulation $C$,

$$
P(A \mid B \cap C) = \frac{P(A \cap B \cap C)}{P(B \cap C)}
$$

by the [law of total probability](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Law_of_total_probability)

$$
P(A \mid B) = \sum_n P(A \mid B \cap C_n) \,P(C_n)
$$

Notice that you incorrectly written it as $P(A \mid B)$, while it obviously depends also on group assignment $C$ if you have different probabilities per each group.